# How to add new key into dictionary like this [{ {]. This looks more like a dictionary inside a list

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

I would like to add new key into the dictionary list. Example:

`"label" : []` (with empty list)

```
[
  {
    "Next" : {
      "seed" : [ 
        {
          "Argument" : [ 
            {
              "id" : 4,
              "label" : "org"
            },
            {
              "id" : "I"
            },
            {
              "word" : "He",
              "seed" : 2,
              "id" : 3,
              "label" : "object"
            },
            {
              "word" : "Gets",
              "seed" : 9,
              "id" : 2,
              "label" : "verb"
            }
          ]
        } 
      ],
      "Next" : "he,get",
      "time" : ""
    }
  }
]
```

I tried to use loop into "seed" and then to "argument" then use .update("label":[]) in the loop but it won't work. Can anyone please give me an example of using for loop to loop from beginning then to add these new "label"?

My prefered goal: ( to have extra "label" within the dictionary according to my input)

Example:

```
[
  {
    "Next" : {
      "seed" : [ 
        {
          "Argument" : [ 
            {
              "id" : 4,
              "label" : "org"
            },
            {
              "id" : "I"
            },
            {
              "word" : "He",
              "seed" : 2,
              "id" : 3,
              "label" : "object"
            },
            {
              "word" : "Gets",
              "seed" : 9,
              "id" : 2,
              "label" : "verb"
            },
            {
              "id" : 5,
              "label" : "EXTRA"
            },
            {
              "id" : 6,
              "label" : "EXTRA"
            },
            {
              "id" : 7,
              "label" : "EXTRA"
            }
          ]
        } 
      ],
      "Next" : "he,get",
      "time" : ""
    }
  }
]
```

I am new to dictionary so really need help with this

Comment: Three questions. Is the second id after "4" meant to be "1"? Where do ids 5 to 7 come from? Where you've written `"label": "EXTRA"`, do you mean to have `"label": []`?

Comment: I wish I could get something like this. those "label" with values should take back its own values while at the same time I wish to include 2-3 more "label" with empty list. string 1 {"label": "new"}, string2{"label":[]} , string 3 {"label": []}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to add 'label' to `dict` in `Argument` where there is no `label`. You could do it like so -

```
for i in x[0]['Next']['seed'][0]['Argument']:
   if not 'label' in i.keys():
       i['label'] = []
```

Where `x` is your dict. But what's `x[0]['Next']['seed'][0]['Argument']:`?
Let's simplify your dict -

```
x = [{'Next': {'Next': 'he,get',
'seed': [{'Argument': [{these}, {are}, {your}, {dicts}]}],
'time': ''}}]
```

How did we reach here?
Let's see-

```
x = [{'Next'(parent dict): {'Next'(child of previous 'Next'):{}, 
'seed(child of previous 'Next')':[{these}, {are}, {your}, {dicts}](a list of dicts)}]
```

I hope that makes sense. And to add more dictionaries in `Argument`

```
# create a function that returns a dict
import random # I don't know how you want ids, so this
def create_dicts():
    return {"id": random.randint(1, 10), "label": ""}
for i in range(3): # 3 is how many dicts you want to push in Argument
    x[0]['Next']['seed'][0]['Argument'].append(create_dicts())
```

Now your `dict` will become -

```
[{'Next': {'Next': 'he,get',
'seed': [{'Argument': [{'id': 4, 'label': 'org'},
  {'id': 'I'},
  {'id': 3, 'label': 'object', 'seed': 2, 'word': 'He'},
  {'id': 2, 'label': 'verb', 'seed': 9, 'word': 'Gets'},
  {'id': 1, 'label': ''},
  {'id': 4, 'label': ''},
  {'id': 4, 'label': ''}]}],
'time': ''}}]
```

Comment: Hi sir, thank you so much for your prompt response. However, in the dict it has already have "label" key and I wanted to add extra "label" keys with empty list into it. Apparently, when I use update, it just update the already existing "label" keys that contain values to empty value. Example; "label": "new" --> "label": [] after using update. What I want is "label": [] x4 extra after "label": "new". Hope this clear the misunderstand a little

Comment: Hi @Joe, you can't have multiple keys with same name in a dict. Look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to put another string like {"label":[]} into the dictionary. I included some example in the post too. The lower part. I hope to make it that way. Is it not possible, sir?

Comment: Oh I understand, you want some of the labels to have a list like `label:[]` but others to have `label: "string here"`, is it so?

Comment: Yes, those "label" with values should take back its own values while at the same time I wish to include 2-3 more "label" with empty list. string 1 {"label": "new"}, string2{"label":[]} , string 3 {"label": []}

Comment: So if `label` exists, you want to update it more values?

Comment: Actually, I wanted to add another pair of key: value ("label":[]) into the dictionary. In the current time. I have 4 strings with 3 "label" keys inside. But I wanted to add another 3 more "label" keys into the dictionary with empty list.

Comment: You want more of `{id:5, label:[]}` in your `Argument` list? I'm sorry I can't seem to understand what exactly that you want. If this is what you want, you can `append` to `Argument` list

Comment: From my above example, I wanted to add this {
        "id" : 5,
        "label" : "EXTRA"
      },
          {
        "id" : 6,
        "label" : "EXTRA"
      },
                  {
        "id" : 7,
        "label" : "EXTRA"
      }

Only to add but not to update it.

Comment: Add these 3 to `Argument` like other dictionaries, yes?

Comment: Yeap, I wish to add these 3 into Argument like other dictionaries.

Comment: @Joe, I hope this is what you wanted?

Comment: Thank you, sir. This is exactly what I wanted it to be. Thank you so much for your prompt response and kind help.

Answer (score 0):

You have a list with *one* nested dictionary. Get the list of the inner dicts, and iterate. Assuming your initial data structure is named *data*

```
dict_list = data[0]['Next']['seed'][0]['Argument']

for item in dict_list:
    item['label'] = input()
```

Comment: Thank you, Sir. But can I know what is the input() for?

Comment: the `input()` is for use input, from the keyboard. If you already have labels, I'll edit

Comment: I wish to do this. those "label" with values should take back its own values while at the same time I wish to include 2-3 more "label" with empty list. string 1 {"label": "new"}, string2{"label":[]} , string 3 {"label": []}

Comment: @Joe: Instead of `input()`, put the value you want, whether it's `"new"` or `[]`. You probably need another function to decide that

Comment: Yes, but I am trying to get more "label" keys into the dictionary and not to make it "new" or []. I wanted to add another pair of key: value ("label":[]) into the dictionary. In the current time. I have 4 strings with 3 "label" keys inside. But I wanted to add another 3 more "label" keys into the dictionary with empty list

Answer (score 0):

First things first: access the list of dict that need to be updated.

according to your given structure that's `l[0]["Next"]["seed"][0]["Argument"]`

Then iterate that list and check if `label` already exists, if it does not then add it as an empty list.

This can be done by explicit checking:

```
if "label" not in i:
    i["label"] = []
```

or by re-assigning:

```
i["label"] = i.get("label", [])
```

Full Code:

```
import pprint
l = [ {
  "Next" : {
    "seed" : [ {
      "Argument" : [ {
        "id" : 4,
        "label" : "org"
      }, {
        "id" : "I"
      }, {
        "word" : "He",
        "seed" : 2,
        "id" : 3,
        "label" : "object"
      }, {
        "word" : "Gets",
        "seed" : 9,
        "id" : 2,
        "label" : "verb"
      } ]
    } ],
    "Next" : "he,get",
    "time" : ""
  } }]

# access the list of dict that needs to be updated
l2 = l[0]["Next"]["seed"][0]["Argument"]
for i in l2:
    i["label"] = i.get("label", []) # use the existing label or add an empty list

pprint.pprint(l)
```

Output:

```
[{'Next': {'Next': 'he,get',
           'seed': [{'Argument': [{'id': 4, 'label': 'org'},
                                  {'id': 'I', 'label': []},
                                  {'id': 3,
                                   'label': 'object',
                                   'seed': 2,
                                   'word': 'He'},
                                  {'id': 2,
                                   'label': 'verb',
                                   'seed': 9,
                                   'word': 'Gets'}]}],
           'time': ''}}]
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. is there a way to include something like the one I wish for in the bottom post above? I would like to add extra "label" with empty list if possible.